# Why are typos given special close treatment?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I recently posted [SE API filter silently fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61429861/se-api-filter-silently-fails) , and it was closed because the error was caused by a typo. Searching the SO help centre for 'typo' does not yield any results.

Given the problem above, I do agree that it was caused by a typo, but I don't agree that it's irreproducible. Copying and pasting the code will reproduce the issue. Isn't that the definition of reproduction?

More broadly: why are typos treated specially on SO? They're "honest mistakes", and honest mistakes of thousands of different flavours are posted on SO every day, and receive helpful, corrective answers. In the case of the above question, the typo had a specific reason - the name of a key in the request matched the name of a key in the response, when it shouldn't. (That asymmetry is bad API design, but that's a different topic.)

I'm not asking for the question to be reopened; I'm trying to understand why the policy is the way it is.

Comment: Typos are trivial mistakes.  This is to discourage people from posting a question every time they forgot the semicolon at the end of a statement.

Comment: You're conflating the two reasons: "This question was caused by a typo **or** a problem that can no longer be reproduced." (emphasis added) It then goes on to say:   "While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers," which is the main thing -- one person's specific day-of typo is unlikely to be searched for, found, and used by someone else -- which is the only reason to leave a question open on SO.

Comment: @PaulRoub I'm not conflating them - SO is. Those two reasons are lumped in with each other in the close rationale.

Comment: @Reinderien Yes, they are definitely mentioned in the same sentence. But that doesn't imply that a typo is necessarily un-reproducible.Two different possible reasons leading to one conclusing: "less likely to help future readers". Reading "or" as "and" doesn't change that.

Comment: You are correct that searching for the exact word "typo" does not produce any results on the help center. However, [searching for that word on Meta Stack Overflow yields over a thousand results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=typo). Searching for the phrase "typographical error" (what "typo" is short for), [yields quite a few results](https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=typographical+error)

Comment: Why is this a bad question? Why is this downvoted? And if it does deserve negative votes, why can I not delete it? None of this makes sense.

Comment: I can't speak for anyone, but downvotes on meta does not necessarily mean that your question is bad, just that people don't agree with you. I think it's general that you can't delete a Question that has a positive scored answer. Doesn't the attempt to delete come with a message?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because generally the solution for a typo question will only be useful for the person who asked the question, and no one else.

The final phrase in the post-notice feedback says:

> this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.

For a single piece of code you can have infinite typo questions, each typo completely unique and the vast majority of them useless for future visitors.

Since even if they have another typo question for an almost identical problem, their typo in all likelihood is going to be a different one.

And if future visitors have a real problem, storing infinite variations of typo questions would only make finding the really unique questions much harder to find.

Comment: By that logic, should syntax errors not also be off-topic? There's an infinite number of ways to produce syntax errors, not all of them typos.

Comment: Many syntax errors are indeed closable with the same reason. Probably most.

Comment: Often with syntax errors, the error message can be used by other people with the same problem to find the question.

Comment: I would argue that ***very*** common typos (including syntax errors) should have a canonical duplicate rather than just closing.  If it is searchable then it is reasonable that a question could exist

Comment: @Psubsee Well of course, the reason explicitly says "this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers." If it's a very common typo, then its solution **is** very likely to help future readers. For example, ["How to write a switch statement in Ruby"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/948135/7795130) is arguably a typo question because Ruby's is called "case" not "switch," however the problem that so many people coming from a language that uses "switch" can't find it in the documentation is solved by that question that gives the correct name for the operator they want.

Comment: @DavyM I know - i only mentioned it as I've seen people arguing to close almost anything related to syntax errors and typos using this close reason even if it seems common and easily searchable

Comment: I think my definition of "typo" differs from others. It is not typing "boolean" where the language expects you to use the keyword "bool", it is misplacing an accolade so all of a sudden the IDE claims half your sourcefile is broken. As an extreme example. A simple example would be to write a comma instead of a dot. Most of the typo problems will lead to random problems, nobody will get the same errors as a result of them in their code and thus they do not make good quality questions as answers help only for the one situation.

Comment: @Gimby Your definition of typo is quite correct. But many syntax errors (as assigning a string to an integer; using the wrong concatenation operator, not using the appropriate character to mark the end of a statement) are also quite useless for future users. They are not searchable, they are quite indistinguishable from a typing accident, and there are infinite variations. There are **some** cases where the Q&A may end up being helpful for future visitors, but it's quite unlikely they haven't been answered already, or that they would benefit from and endless stream of dupe pointing to them.